# Initializing custom view in Android Studio: Expected resource of type xml

Tags: android-studio, android-custom-view, compiler-warnings, android-resources

I have a custom view called `IconView`, which has the following constructor for initialization:

```
public class IconView extends RelativeLayout implements Checkable {

    ...

    public IconView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, boolean useDefaultImage) {
        super(context, attrs);
        inflateLayout(context);

    ...
```

In order to initialize `AttributeSet` instance from XMLfor constructing the view, I use `getResources().getXml(R.layout.icon_view), false);`.
This compiles successfully and runs correctly. However, Android studio highlights the code and displays me this error:

[image: Screenshot of the error in Android Studio]

The detailed description of the error is here:

Expected resource of type xml less... (Ctrl+F1) 
Reports two types of problems:

- Supplying the wrong type of resource identifier. For example, when
  calling Resources.getString(int id), you should be passing
  R.string.something, not R.drawable.something.
- Passing the wrong
  constant to a method which expects one of a specific set of
  constants. For example, when calling View#setLayoutDirection, the
  parameter must be android.view.View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_LTR or
  android.view.View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL.

**The question:**

Although the code works, I do not know, how to rewrite it, so that the error would disappear in Android Studio. The error is visually annoying, so how could I get rid of it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Resources#getXml(int id)` is used to get the resource of type *xml*, which lays inside the `xml` resource folder. You, on the other hand, passing `R.layout.icon_view` here, the *layout* resource.
Use `getResources().getLayout(R.layout.icon_view)` here and the error will disappear.

P.S.: the documentation on `Resources#getLayout()` says the following:

> This function is really a simple wrapper for calling getXml(int) with a layout resource.

So it looks like this is some kind of lint-related issue. Either way, `getLayout()` does not result in this error.